# Are there any dictionaries that be able to look up words in word families?

Tags: dictionaries

I was wondering there are any dictionaries/a dictionary that if I search for a word, for example: news, the dictionary will provide its word family or any types of usages related to this word, for example: news -> {reading, magazine, politics, amusing, global warming, accident, ..}.

Comment: [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/)?

Comment: Because the idea of "types of usages related to this word" is so inexact, it's unlikely that someone would create such a product. It's possible you could find some machine learning/classification to find, say, verbs that occur frequently around your noun, though. In any case, is that an EL&U question?

Comment: Thanks. So, are there any dictionaries could give a word list related to a chosen word?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources

Comment: @ielearner: Obviously a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/) would have some relevance. I also have paper-based "Crossword Solver" books, but I don't know what's available online in that area. [Google Instant](http://www.google.co.uk/instant/) would also seem relevant.

Comment: I fail to see how *reading*, *amusing* and *global warming* can be considered to be in a "family".

Answer (score 1):

The [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/) often provides example usages, along with the meanings, of words.

See [this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/news) definition of *news*, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your comments. I found exactly what I need (reverse dictionary): http://www.wordinaire.com/

Comment: [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) is another one. However, a reverse dictionary is something entirely different from what you asked for in the question. In fact it does not return *any* of your example words for "news" (*reading, magazine, politics, amusing, global warming, accident*). Now, of course it can still be exactly what you need, but then the question stated very poorly what it was that you needed. And it is a duplicate to boot.